# can't paste the project file into the htdocs on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, command-line, software-installation, network-manager

for command

```
sudo usermod  -R root.xamppusers /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

....it shows

```
usermod: invalid chroot path 'root.xamppusers'
```

Comment: Why did you tag 14.04?   Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL & thus off-topic, Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is off-topic as all ESM releases are being supported only through Ubuntu Advantage offered by Canonical.  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use change the owner of the folder. Use `chown` ("change owner") instead of `usermod`:

```
  sudo chown -R root.xamppusers /opt/lampp/htdocs
```